# Ошибка header location

Tags: php, header

уважаемые люди.

Подскажите в чём именно проблема? Даёт две ошибки

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /var/www/u0712326/data/www/code21.info/login/login.php:5) in
>   /var/www/u0712326/data/www/code21.info/login/login.php on line 10
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /var/www/u0712326/data/www/code21.info/login/login.php:5) in
>   /var/www/u0712326/data/www/code21.info/login/login.php on line 33

Сам код: https://codeshare.io/GkXNYM

Были уже многие темы - решения к сожелению не помогли в моем случае :с

Буду очень признателен за помощь. А так же извиняюсь за бардак в коде :)

Comment: @u_mulder Не дубликат. Решения проблемы там нету - конкретно в моем случае.

Comment: Решение проблемы всегда одно - __ничего не выводить или буферизовать вывод__ до установки заголовков. А вам требуется прочитать сначала ответ и только потом делать выводы. Спасибо.

Comment: @Андрей, Вам верно ответили, у вас ошибка из-за того что вы до заголовков уже выводите что-то.. У вашем случае это строки между закрывающими и открывающими `<?php ... ?>` тегами.. Зачем они вам нужны если у вас везде только php код? Откройте вначале и дальше просто код добавляйте, не нужно их сотню раз открывать-закрывать

Comment: Это абсолютно полный дубликат, вы зря думаете, что решения там нету. Проверьте, наверняка у вас BOM до первых символов <? есть или пробелы между ?><?

Comment: output started at /var/www/u0712326/data/www/code21.info/login/login.php:5 - в этой строчке у вас require_once("connection.php"); Проверьте его сами (connection.php) на предмет вывода чего-либо или приложите к вопросу.